# Show/Hide div search-dropdown by mouseclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a div-block in order to search items in a catalogue.
Actually I have the same result like here (http://demos.sshopwp.com/) but i need to remove the dropdown effect over the search symbol and replace it by mouseclick.
My current idea is to add a js code that is able to overwrite the css effect but it doesn't work.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="header-shop__icon search-icon has-dropdown">
                        <a href=""><span id="search-on"
                            class="shop__icon fa fa-search"></span></a>
                        <div class="header-dropdown">
                            <form class="top-search-form header-dropdown-inner">
                                <div class="input-group" id="search-div">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control clearable"
                                        id="search-string" placeholder="Search..."
                                        aria-describedby="basic-addon2" size="100">
                                    <button id="search-item" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                        type="submit">Search Item</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS CODE:

```
$jq('#search-on').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $jq(".header-dropdown").css('style1', 'overflow: visible !important;');

});
```

CSS:

```
.header-shop__icon .header-dropdown {
    display: hide;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    z-index: 9;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
}
```

Any other ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: what libraries are you using?

Comment: actually only JQuery. Framework Bootstrap 4

Comment: Let me know if it [helps](https://codepen.io/akshay-sarkar/pen/wXLRyO)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this working when you hover over it, you can put the icon in an anchor tag and use the :active pseudo-class on the anchor tag instead of the :hover pseudo-class on the icon.

Alternatively, simply define the css you wish to dynamically put on the box with an additional class in the selector, and use the JS to toggle that class when clicking on the icon or away from the icon. Like so:

JS:

```
$jq('#search-on').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $jq(".header-dropdown").addClass("visible");
});
```

CSS:

```
.header-shop__icon .header-dropdown {
    display: hide;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    z-index: 9;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
}
.header-shop__icon .header-dropdown.visible {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works proprerly! Now, how can I remove the dropdown effetc if the mouse goes over the search symbol?

Comment: I've tried in the following way but it still doesn't work <br/> JS <br/>  $jq('#search-on').hover(function(){
         $jq(".header-dropdown").addClass("hidden");
    });  <br/> CSS  <br/> .header-shop__icon .header-dropdown.hidden {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

Comment: I haven't used bootstrap much because I don't really care for it, but I would bet that the classes you have defined on these are causing bootstrap to do the hover reveal for you. Try changing the classes on them to make sure boot strap isn't doing anything to it. If that doesn't work look through your css for any :hover pseudoclass on these items.